# View not updating after http call in Angular2 / Ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a simple Ionic2 page which need to fetch data from the server and display it in the template.

When I run the application I see in my console all the fetched data from `console.log(res.Data);` appearing.

Unfortunately the view is not updated. However when I press the button everything works like a charm.

I have also to call `this.update()` from the `ngOnInit` method without success. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong here?

**Code**

```
constructor(private timeline: TimelineService) {
    this.update();
}

update() {

  this.timeline.getTimeline(1).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.Data);
    this.timelineData = res.Data;
  });

}
```

**Template**

```
<pre>
    {{ timelineData?.length }}
</pre>

<button (click)="update()">Update</button>

<div *ngFor="#timelineItem of timelineData; #i = index">
    <timeline-item [data]="timelineItem"></timeline-item>
</div>
```

Comment: did you tried calling update function from `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.. like `ngOnInit(){ this.update(); }` ?

Comment: It might just be an issue with your timeline-item component. What if you just do {{ timelineItem }} inside the ngFor instead of calling that component

Comment: It indeed looks like it has something todo with the timeline-item-component. Going to strip this one and see what is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem in your template. Since your data are loaded asynchronously, you should have a problem when trying to display its `length` property.

You could try the Elvis operator at this level:

```
<pre>
  {{ timelineData?.length }}
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Could you provide the way you defined your component? I mean what you have in `@Component`...

Comment: It's not a `Component` but a `Page` from Ionic2. Perhaps I need to put everything in a component. Hang on :)

Comment: This should also work in a page ;-) Let me make a try... That said, I would leverage the `onPageWillEnter` hook to load your data in an Ionic2 page ;-)

Comment: It looks like it works in a Component but not in a Page. Weird :) Still wondering why you would choose for `onPageWillEnter` over `onInit` :)

Comment: It's when you use `PageController` ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110260/discussion-between-osi-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: Which version of Ionic2 do you use since it works on my side (i.e. within a `@Page`) both from constructor and ngOnInit?

Comment: For Ionic I use 2.0.0-beta.6

Comment: I use 2.0.0-beta.24 ;-) Would it be possible for you to upgrade?

Comment: Done now on `ionic@2.0.0-beta.25` same problem :P

Comment: Grr! Could you provide the complete code of your page? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting it I guess. I used `value` and `data` as properties for my custom components. It looks like renaming them fixed it. Quite hard to spot as an error ;) Now checking everything to be sure it works

Comment: Still doesn't work too bad. When I just show the json in my view it is no problem. When I pass it to a component it fails. When I press the button it works :S

Answer (score 0):

I have similar work around and calling service under onPageLoaded() works like a charm. Did you try this?

```
constructor(private timeline: TimelineService) {
}
onPageLoaded(){
 this.update();
}
update() {
  this.timeline.getTimeline(1).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.Data);
    this.timelineData = res.Data;
  });
}
```